# How to call callback after dynamic form submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call javascript ajax function after successful dynamically created form submit.

Or how to check the form was successfully submitted or not using java script .

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to check if the form was submitted and also an example of how to handle a callback:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var handleSubmit = function (e) {
  // remove the preventDefault
  // added just to demonstrate the value is true
  // without proceeding with submittion and pg refresh
  e.preventDefault()
  form.setAttribute('data-submitted', true)
  console.log(form.getAttribute('data-submitted'))
  handleAjaxCall()
}
var handleAjaxCall = function () {
  console.log('ajax call here!')
}
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit, false)
```

```html
<form data-submitted="0">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form data-submitted="0" action="test.php">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form> Function must call after test.php process

Comment: @user7726968 Once the form submits the browser loads the new page, replacing the current one, so trying to run a function on the current page after the form has submitted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How to shall I know the  dynamic form was successfully submitted . I need to track  more than  site  contact form submission.

Comment: Provided you with a way to check if submitted, plus how to handle a callback. The rest is up to you.